# How to use between expression with concatenated columns

Tags: mysql, sql, string-concatenation, between

I'm trying to fetch data from one table. But this is an old table and there are thousands rows in it but date column seperated. I mean, month and year in different columns.

```
|id | member | month | year | balance |
|-------------------------------------|
|1  | 1001   | 11    | 2013 | 100     |
|2  | 1002   | 11    | 2013 | 120     |
|3  | 1003   | 11    | 2013 | 105     |
|4  | 1001   | 12    | 2013 | 140     |
|5  | 1002   | 12    | 2013 | 130     |
|6  | 1003   | 12    | 2013 | 80      |
|7  | 1001   | 1     | 2014 | 90      |
|8  | 1002   | 1     | 2014 | 20      |
|9  | 1003   | 1     | 2014 | 180     |
--------------------------------------|
```

This is the sample table. I try to get data between month 10th 2013 and month 2nd 2014.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(balance) 
FROM 
    sample_table 
WHERE 
    CONCAT(month,year) BETWEEN 102013 AND 022014
```

This query gives me empty result. How could I get the true result ? Anyone can give me an idea.

-- EDIT --

Date range can be change. So, between is best solution if I can get the true result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try expressing the `where` clause like this:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) 
FROM sample_table 
WHERE year*100 + month between 201301 and 201402;
```

That is, do the comparison as numbers rather than strings.  With strings, you have the problem of leading zeros to get correct comparisons.

More importantly, use the format YYYYMM instead of MMYYYY.  The former works for comparisons, the latter does not.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. I cahnge my where expression as like yours and it works now. And thanks for the extra explanation for date format.